# How to update resx file dynamically ( client can update value )

Tags: c#, resx

I need to allow client to add his own language texts for labels which are under resx file. We have created resx file which contain translate text for languages.

Now client wants this feature available to his side. Generally we given option to change his language and by selection we shows label from resx file.

so we need to update this resx file dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to add / update a ResX File:

```
ResXResourceWriter rsxw = new ResXResourceWriter(path);
bool added = false;
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry node in reader)
    {
        if (key == node.Key.ToString())
        {
             rsxw.AddResource(key, value);
             added = true;
        }
        else rsxw.AddResource(node.Key.ToString(), node.Value);
    }
}
if(!added) rsxw.AddResource(key, value);
rsxw.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the resx file as a fallback that is not changeable. To change it clientside is difficult and not a good approach in my opinion. As already suggested, create a database- or XML-based "override" pack. If value x has a definition within this pack, use this. Otherwise use the resx (fallback) value that is provided for value x.